# How can I merge 2 tables into one in dataverse?

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, dataverse

So I am having extreme difficulty getting a "template" excel file to upload into dataverse. Whenever I try to publish it always fails i have tried everything imaginable.

What I have done to counteract this is split my data into 2 different MS Access tables that have a limit around 230 columns ish (not sure why it works) but it uploads both into my dataverse as "table 1" and "table 2"....

Now my problem is I want to merge both table 1 and 2 together. There is no associated data rows, really I want them for the headers. I would manually do it but there are a total of 433 columns and I don't want to manually do all of that if possible.

The end goal is to have a Power automate feed data into this singular repository for collection when a form is submitted.

In conclusion both desired tables are in the dataverse but not combined.

Example:

Table 1:
column 1| column 2| ..... |column 233|

Table 2:
Colum 234| column 235|... |column 433|

"Ideal solution" Table 3: (this is how it is formatted in excel)
Column 1| column 2| .... |column 433|

Comment: What error message do you receive when the dataflow fails?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the type of columns being added, you might be hitting SQL Server limits.

Supposedly there is a limit of 1024 columns on a table, but because some Dataverse column types consume more than 1 "sql" column, you could hit your limit earlier than expected:

> - Lookup fields take up 3 columns.
> - Option sets, boolean, and money fields take up 2 columns.
> - All other field types take up 1 column.